# Re-route server-side 404 with client-side Blazor router?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I've just started playing around with Blazor and I'm using the standalone client-side routing but I'm curious if something like this is possible. Let's say I have a blazor app that has a page called **test** and navigating to that page in the client-side router gives me a URL like: **http://{site}/test**. I've set my web server to re-route any 404s to the index so Blazor's router can do the work but is there any way I can actually have **http://{site}/test** be sent to Blazor's client-side router and then resolved correctly?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get this to work by creating a .htaccess file with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```